# Searching a site, metas perhaps?, with php

Tags: php

If one were to want to search OTHER websites for information, how would one go about this using php?

Sorry, let me clarify as this is rather vague: lets say I have a user input field with check boxes, the user selects an option and submits it, its stored in, lets say `$variabletest`. Now I want to search X sites where `$variabletest == tags`. Tags as in video tags uploaded by users on X site, X site is predetermined and no doubt more than one site.

I hope this clarifies, I'm good at programming to communiacte with sql, not so much application creation :P but I suppose I'm wondering what is the best way to go about this, search by meta tags? I dont need all of the code written for me, just a nice sized shove in the right direction. Thanks in advance

> i have lets say, 7 sites with videos. My user selects what things they would like to see in a video via checkboxes, and my php script, essentially "crawls" through each of the 7 sites and sesrches for what my user has chosen. Maybe by tags on videos, or metas even. Thus is my predicament

Comment: there is no general answer which would apply to all sites. Answers could range from using an API (for something like YouTube), to implementing a web crawler and storing the results somewhere for later fast searching (ie: re-making a 90's search-engine). Can you be any more specific about your situation?

Comment: I have lets say, 7 sites with videos. My user selects what things they would like to see in a video via checkboxes, and my php script, essentially "crawls" through each of the 7 sites and sesrches for what my user has chosen. Maybe by tags on videos, or metas even. Thus is my predicament.

Comment: Edit your question and add your predicament there, not in a comment, that way other can read the full question and give a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
// assuming an array of urls such as $urls = array("http://...","http://...")
// could easily be modified to use urls from a database output

function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}



for each ($urls as $url){
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    //get and display what you need:
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
            $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }

    echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
    echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
    echo "Keywords: $keywords";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, two quick questions: I assume $url is the url in variable? Also, I slightly see how this could work for one page, but what if I had a directory full of html files that needed searched? Would I set $url to directory and then put the.curl function in a while loop? sorry shot in the dark there:p but thank you fire the answer regardless, it leaves me a lot to learn.

Comment: I have just edited the answer that harinder added. It will take a while for the mods to validate it. It would be better to put the whole lot in a function and reference it within a for loop rather than the edit i did, but it will work :)

Comment: @nick behrends Thx Chris ... Nick You can use this script for as many site u want ($url is your url)... Is that Directory on your server? ... if so why dont  you use mysql to search your own pages .... yes you can use loop to check your html files

Comment: @nick behrends if this answer solves your problem accept it and close the answer (so it it get removed from unanswered questions)... thx